# yii2: model relations error can't find another class in ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: yii2, ubuntu-16.04, yii2-active-records

I have upload my YII2 project to ubuntu 16.04.
My source is no problem when run on localhost on my computer, but when I run it on the server ubuntu 16.04 with network, it has a problem.
The model source can't find another relation model

```
public function getLokasiAwal()
{
    return $this->hasOne(KotaBandara::className(), ['id_kota' => 'lokasi_awal']);
}
```

and i have error

> Class 'backend\models\TypeNonstaf' not found

I have found the solution, I added the following code:

```
use backend\models\Kotabandara;
```

On top in model file but, in my source in localhost, 
I do not need to add that code

Can someone explain that issue??

Comment: And im guessing that your localhost is windows?

Comment: Make sure that your files names has the same case as class names. In your example you have two versions of model name: `Kotabandara` and `KotaBandara`.

Comment: @Yupik is my localhost is windows

Comment: @rob006 no problem with that case sensitive in windows

Comment: Because Windows is not case sensitive.

Comment: @rob006 oh my god, that work, thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rob006 pointed out, it appears that you had been working/running your app on a Windows local file system, which is case-preserving, but **not** *case-sensitive*.

When you first call upon a namespaced class directly or via the `use` operator, it passes this full class name as `$className` into `yii\BaseYii\autoload::($className)` (Yii2's global class autoloading handler), which in turn attempts to `include` the corresponding class file, if found.

So, on your Windows local machine, when you use `backend\models\KotaBandara`, it will find and include any file associated with the corresponding path alias in a case-insensitive manner, thus it will find any of:

- `@backend/models/KotaBandara.php`
- `@backend/models/Kotabandara.php`
- `@backend/models/kotabandara.php`
- `@backend/models/KoTaBaNdArA.php`

There can be only 1 target file with this sequence of paths/characters anyway.

However, when you migrate this code to a Ubuntu system, which is both case-preserving **and** *case-sensitive*, there is a distinct difference between `KotaBandara.php` and `kotabandara.php` and in fact both files can exist side by side, unlike on Windows.

So, you have to be precise here - on Ubuntu, `use backend\models\KotaBandara` will trigger the autoloader to find only the file whose path AND case matches, i.e. `KotaBandara.php`. If you named the file `kotabandara.php`, it will be found on Windows, but not on Ubuntu!